# How can lsof report a higher number than the ulimit?

Tags: file-descriptors, lsof, ulimit

From time to time some user consumes all the file descriptors (FDs) on a RHEL Linux machine. I have started logging the FDs per user to see the actual state. The logging is run as root to have access to all of the FDs. The script is simple and uses the following command to count the FDs per user:

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | grep -v UID | xargs -I {} bash -c 'printf "{} "; /usr/sbin/lsof -u {} | wc -l ' | sort -n -k2
```

I also want to compute the ratios of the actual FDs and the maximal available FDs per user for which I used the `ulimit -Sn` command. Nevertheless, either the soft limit returned or the counted FDs are incorrect as for some user I have `1555 as actual count and 1024 as soft limit set`. I have no problem with the max values of users which have these in `/etc/security/limit.conf` .

**In summary,** I am not sure whether the `root> lsof -u <user>` lists only the unique FDs or it also includes more references to the same FD. In the latter case, how could I count the FDs in a correct manner?

How would you solve the problem?

Comment: Does any **single** process from this user use more than 1024 FD?

Comment: that looks like a horribly inefficient way of getting the number of FDs per user.  Use `pidstat` from the [sysstat](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/) package instead.   e.g. (as root) `pidstat -v | perl -lane 'next if $. <=3; $u[$F[1]] += $F[4]}; END {foreach $i (0..$#u) { $n = (getpwuid($i) || $i); print $n, ": ", $u[$i] if $u[$i]}'  | sort -t: -k2rn`

Comment: or to find processes with more than 1024 FDs:   `pidstat -v | awk 'NR<=3 || $5 > 1024'`

Comment: Thanks. No single process exceeds 1024 but the sum of the FDs for all processes of the users are greater than 1024. The question is actually whether lsof -u <user> lists unique FDs or it includes the same FD several times?